# How to debug dataflow template udf output

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The job is now outputting any successful rows. All of the InvokeUDF stage are outputting to ProcessedUDF.out0 rather than ProccessedUDF.out1. see
[image]

How can I debug this when using the template? Stackdriver is not showing any relevant logs.

Answer (score 1):

I was sending the wrong format of message. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faexdxtZGno) helped me understand the issue.